# Barret reduction to get 64-bit remainder of a 128-bit number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

On github there's this [code part of Microsoft's SEAL](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/d045f1beff96dff0fccc7fa0c5acb1493a65338c/native/src/seal/util/polyarithsmallmod.cpp#L144):

```
SEAL_ITERATE(iter(operand1, operand2, result), coeff_count, [&](auto I) {
    // Reduces z using base 2^64 Barrett reduction
    unsigned long long z[2], tmp1, tmp2[2], tmp3, carry;
    multiply_uint64(get<0>(I), get<1>(I), z);

    // Multiply input and const_ratio
    // Round 1
    multiply_uint64_hw64(z[0], const_ratio_0, &carry);
    multiply_uint64(z[0], const_ratio_1, tmp2);
    tmp3 = tmp2[1] + add_uint64(tmp2[0], carry, &tmp1);

    // Round 2
    multiply_uint64(z[1], const_ratio_0, tmp2);
    carry = tmp2[1] + add_uint64(tmp1, tmp2[0], &tmp1);

    // This is all we care about
    tmp1 = z[1] * const_ratio_1 + tmp3 + carry;

    // Barrett subtraction
    tmp3 = z[0] - tmp1 * modulus_value;

    // Claim: One more subtraction is enough
    get<2>(I) = SEAL_COND_SELECT(tmp3 >= modulus_value, tmp3 - modulus_value, tmp3);
});
```

that is supposed to do [Barrett Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction), a technique for calculating modulus without division.

It looks like `multiply_uint64_hw64` multiplies two 64-bit numbers and get only the 64 most significant bits. `multiply_uint64` gets a 128 bit number in two 64 bit numbers. However, I don't understand what's being done, and most importantly, where does

$$a-\left\lfloor a\,s\right\rfloor\,n$$

happen. There's not even a floor function on this code.

Comment: The code multiplies inputs `get<0>(I)` and `get<1>(I)` into `z`, then reduces `z` modulo constant `modulus_value`$=n$, with the outcome `get<2>(I)`. The $s=1/n$ in the linked wiki on Barrett reduction is scaled to $r=\lfloor2^{128}/n\rfloor$, precomputed externally as `const_ratio_0`  and `const_ratio_1` (low and high 64-bit limbs). If something remains mysterious, please pinpoint it; and preferably transcribe what you understand (including my hints) in the question, giving variables nice and consistent names with e.g. $r_0+2^{64}r_1=r$ for `const_ratio`, same for `z` and `tmp2`.

Comment: @fgrieu I basically didn't understand the separation into most and least significant bits. How can multiplication work with upper and bottom parts? I understood how `const_ratio` is broken into 2 pieces but not how things are done after that

Comment: Maybe I'm too simple here, but with integer operations you don't need a floor, as rounding down is the same as forgetting everything behind the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question's code computes the 64-bit `get<2>(I)`=$h:=f\,g\bmod n$ from inputs:

- 64-bit `modulus_value`=$n$ with $n\in[2,\,2^{63}]$
- 64-bit `get<0>(I)`=$f$ with $f\in[0,\,2^{64}-1]$
- 64-bit `get<1>(I)`=$g$ with $g\in[0,\,2^{64}-1]$ and $f\,g<2^{64}\,n$, a condition that's met if $f,g\in[0,\,n-1]$ (which I guess is always the case in the application).

The result $h$ is the remainder of the Euclidean division of $f\,g$ by $n$. It is mathematically defined by $0\le h<m$ and $\exists q\in\mathbb Z,\ f\,g=q\cdot n+h$.

The code first computes the 128-bit `z`$=z:=f\,g$, then the result `get<2>(I)`$=h:=z\bmod n$ by [Barrett reduction](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-47721-7_24):

- It was precomputed (externally to the question's code)  `const_ratio`$=r=\left\lfloor2^{128}/n\right\rfloor$
- $\hat q:=\left\lfloor z\,r/2^{128}\right\rfloor$, which is the correct $q$ within one by default (note: $\hat q$ is the final value of variable `tmp1`).
- $\hat h:=z-q\cdot n$, which is the correct $h$ within possibly an excess of exactly $n$ (note: $\hat h$ is the final value of variable `tmp3`).
- $h:=\hat h-n$ when $\hat h\ge n$, or $h:=\hat h$ otherwise.

The code uses primary school algorithms to perform multiple-digit arithmetic, transposed from base $10$ to base $2^{64}$ (with optimizations and a variant detailed in the next section). The equivalent of digits are so-called *limbs*, here 64-bit.

The product `z`$=z$ is expressed as two limbs `z[0]`$=z_0$ (low-order), `z[1]`$=z_1$ (high-order), thus with $z=z_0+2^{64}\,z_1$, and $z_0, z_1\in[0,\,2^{64}-1]$.

The Barrett multiplier `const_ratio`$=r=\left\lfloor2^{128}/n\right\rfloor$ is similarly expressed as two limbs `const_ratio_0`$=r_0$ and `const_ratio_1`$=r_1$, thanks to the low end of the interval in the precondition $n\in[2,\,2^{63}]$.

The intermediary product $z\,r$ always fits three limbs (even though in general the product of two quantities expressed as two limbs would require four limbs).

The tentative quotient by default $\hat q$ fits a single limb, since $\hat q\le q$ and $q<2^{64}$, with the latest insured by the input precondition $f\,g<2^{64}\,n$.

The tentative remainder $\hat h$ fits a single limb, since $\hat h<2n$ and $2n\le2^{64}$, with the later thanks to the high end of the interval in the precondition $n\in[2,\,2^{63}]$.

---

Detailing the code's algorithm (as asked in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/206549) and bounty):

I'll use an illustration in decimal. In that base, since $2\le n\le10/2$, `const_ratio`$=r$ can only be $\left\lfloor100/2\right\rfloor=50$, $\left\lfloor100/3\right\rfloor=33$, $\left\lfloor100/4\right\rfloor=25$, $\left\lfloor100/5\right\rfloor=20$, but I'll pretend `const_ratio`$=r=29$ because that makes a more interesting example. For the same reason I'll use `z`$=z=34$, even though that can't be obtained as the product of two digits.

The product `z` is obtained in the code by `multiply_uint64(get<0>(I), get<1>(I), z)` as two limbs `z[0]` and `z[1]`.

The meat of the computation is $\hat q:=\left\lfloor z\,r/2^{128}\right\rfloor$. That's the analog in base $2^{64}$ of $9:=\left\lfloor29\cdot34/100\right\rfloor$ in base 10. Both arguments $29$ and $34$ to the multiplication are two-digit, but small enough that their product $986$ is three-digit (rather than four), and we are only interested in the third digit from the right. The primary school algorithm to compute $986:=29\cdot34$ would be presented as

```
      2 9   const_ratio
   x  3 4   z
    -----
    1 1 6
+   8 7
  -------
    9 8 6
```

In the primary school algorithm there are four single-digit multiplications (which the code performs) and a few extra operations (that the code reorganizes slightly):

- `4` times `9`, `36`; write `6`, keep `3`;
- `4` times `2`,  `8`; plus `3` (kept), `11`; write that.
- `3` times `9`, `27`; write `7`, keep `2`;
- `3` times `2`,  `6`; plus `2` (kept),  `8`; write that.

The first of these four multiplications occurs in the code fragment `multiply_uint64_hw64(z[0], const_ratio_0, &carry)`, which multiplies the low-order limb of $r$ with the low-order limb of $z$, like we multiply the low-order digit `4` of `34` with the low-order digit `9` of `29`. Notice that "write `6`" is pointless in the circumstance, since whatever digit it writes will stay segregated to the right column of the computation without any opportunity to influence a leftmost digit, and ignored when we divide by 100 and round down (equivalently, keep only the third digit from the right). That's why the low-order 64-bit of the 128-bit product is not even computed, as noted in the question. The equivalent of `3` in `36` is kept in `carry`.

The second multiplication occurs in `multiply_uint64(z[0], const_ratio_1, tmp2)`, which multiplies the high-order limb of $r$ with the low-order limb of $z$, with result in the two limbs of `tmp2`; the 64-bit `tmp[0]` receives the equivalent of `8` in  `8`, and `tmp[1]` receives the equivalent of `0` for   (notice a leading `0` is suppressed in the conventional writing of decimal integers). The equivalent of `8 plus 3` occurs in `add_uint64(tmp2[0], carry, &tmp1)`, with the low-order digit `1` of the result `11` in `tmp1`, and the new carry `1` in the output of that function. That's used as right operand in `tmp3 = tmp2[1] + …` (which happens to be skipped in the primary school algorithm with the particular example I took since the `0` was suppressed), yielding the equivalent of the left `1` in `116`. [Note on the output of `add_uint64`: it's generated by `static_cast<unsigned char>(*result < operand1)`, which compares `*result` and `operand`, then turns `true` to `1`, `false` to `0`. Made after `*result = operand1 + operand2`, that tells if this addition generated a carry. Some compilers recognize this idiom, use the C bit of the status word, and reuse C in the forthcoming addition].

The third multiplication occurs in `multiply_uint64(z[1], const_ratio_0, tmp2)`, which multiplies the low-order limb of $r$ with the high-order limb of $z$, with result on to limbs in `tmp2`, like we do `3 x 9 = 27`. This time we need both limbs/digits: the equivalent of `7` goes to `tmp2[0]` and the equivalent of `2` goes to `tmp2[1]`. Here it's made a variant of the primary school algorithm: it's immediately added `tmp1` (the equivalent of the middle `1` in `116`) to the low-order limb with `add_uint64(tmp1, tmp2[0], &tmp1)`, performing the equivalent of `1 + 7 =  8`, no carry. The result `8` is stored in `tmp1` because the semantic of `add_uint64` needs a destination, but it's really ignored, because we don't care for the middle digit in `986`. The carry output by `add_uint64` is used as right operand in `carry = tmp2[1] + …`, performing the equivalent of `1 + 0 = 1` in our example. Despite the name `carry`, that holds a full-blown 64-bit limb/digit.

The fourth multiplication occurs in `z[1] * const_ratio_1`, which multiplies the high-order limb of $r$ with the high-order limb of $z$, like we do `3 x 2 = 6`. Here the context insures the result fits a single limb, thus the native C operator for multiplication can be used. The outcome is then used as the left operator of `… + tmp3 + carry`, performing the equivalent of `6 + 1 + 1 = 8`. Again the context insures this values $\hat q$, stored in `tmp1`, fits a single limb/digit.

Then `tmp3 = z[0] - tmp1 * modulus_value` performs $\hat h:=z-q\cdot n$. The context insures the mathematically exact result fits a single limb/digit (stored in `tmp3`) even though $q\cdot n$ does not. This allows the use of the native C operators, which skip computing the high-order limb entirely.

Then `SEAL_COND_SELECT(tmp3 >= modulus_value, tmp3 - modulus_value, tmp3)` computes $h$ from $\hat h$ by conditionally subtracting $n$ when $\hat h\ge n$. The selection operator is hidden in a macro.

Two examples for base $2^{64}$ (values in big-endian hexadecimal with space inserted between limbs):

```
modulus_value                      000076513ae0b1cd
const_ratio       00000000000229e6 7f4ca82ba3a115f1
get<0>(I)                          00005f0fd669f2c7
get<1>(I)                          000041a1f91ef16f
z                 00000000185f2ae8 a455846cb7cf9b49
tmp1                               000034bb854f9a8d
tmp3                               00000fcebfd55b60
get<2>(I)                          00000fcebfd55b60

modulus_value                      686f4b7702a9c775
const_ratio       0000000000000002 7387d66ffd685b82
get<0>(I)                          536094611fa2b19b
get<1>(I)                          675ef5187093ff63
z                 21aac8fcf31d6421 62e675ba16d513f1
tmp1                               5287278703394bb1
tmp3                               72b1d3d2b9f5e50c
get<2>(I)                          0a42885bb74c1d97
```

---

Note: for $n\in[2^{63}+1,\,2^{64}-1]$, the quantity $\hat h$ can overflow one limb and the code as it stands fails. E.g. for input $f=g=2^{32}$, we get $z=2^{64}$ thus $\hat q=0$ (for any $n>2^{63}$), thus $\hat h=z=2^{64}$ and an output of $0$ rather than the true $h=2^{64}-n$. The full source has a comment "the Modulus class represents a non-negative integer modulus up to 61 bits", thus such issues for large $n$ occurs only when the calling code errs. Plus, if I understand correctly, $n=2^{60}-2^{14}+1$ is the main target.

---

Alternative: For something performing the same function as the question's code, in 4 short lines of code instead of 11, for all $n\in[1,\,2^{64}-1]$, needing no precomputation, possibly faster, but compatible only with recent x64 compilers+CPUs, see the first of [these code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647527/903600) (the second is a small variant without the restriction $f\,g<2^{64}\,n$ ). I make no statement about constant-timeness of either code.

Comment: Why does `add_uint64` always return $0$ or $1$? Isn't there bigger carry possibility?

Comment: @Guerlando OCs: `add_uint64` adds two limbs passed as first and second arguments, thus two quantities in $[0,\ 2^{64}-1]$. The mathematically exact result thus is in $[0,\ 2^{65}-2]$, thus fits one 64-bit limb and one bit. That's similar to the sum of two decimal digits fitting one digit and a carry 0 (e.g. 4+5=9) or 1 (e.g. 9+9=18).